# git аналог "svn co path/dir/ . "

Tags: git

На продакшене есть папка "DIRX".

Есть репозиторий со структурой:

```
MainDIR
-dir0
-dir1
-dir2
```

Как получить содержимое папки MainDIR/dir1 в продакшен папку DIRX используя гит?

С SVN это делается так:

```
cd DIRX
svn co //path/dir/ .
```

C гитом получилось забрать папку вместе с её созданием*, забрать содержимое отдельно не получилось.

*т.е получилось вот так:

```
DIRX/dir1/
```

Так же, если такое решение существует, как потом обновлять (забирать актуальные изменения в) эту папку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предуведомление: исхожу из предположения, что в репозитории у вас хранится каталог `dir1`, а не `MainDIR/dir1`. если всё-таки `MainDIR/dir1`, то замените последний параметр программы *git* и увеличьте на единицу значение опции `strip` программы *tar*.

---

например, так: с помощью `git archive` создать архив из нужных файлов/каталогов, а затем разархивировать их в нужном месте, «обрезав» нужное количество «лишних» компоненты в пути к файлам/каталогам:

```
$ git archive --remote=url-репозитория ветка dir1 | tar -x --strip=1 -C /путь/к/DIRX
```

- `url-репозитория` — *url* репозитория в любом виде, понятном программе *git*.
- `ветка` — тут может быть, например, `master`.
- `dir1` — последними аргументами команде *archive* можно передать пути к файлам, каталогам, которые будут включены в создаваемый архив.
- `--strip=1` — опция программы *tar*, «обрезающая» компоненты пути при распаковке. например, в архиве содержится `dir/subdir/file`. если не указывать опцию, именно так и распакуется. если указать `--strip=1`, то распакуется `subdir/file`, а если `--strip=2`, то только `file`.
- `-C /путь/куда/распаковывать` — эта опция на тот случай, когда вы не хотите (или по каким-то причинам не можете) предварительно сделать `cd /путь/куда/распаковывать`.

---

обновлять этот каталог можно той же самой командой.